# problem with arabic ( م ) character in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, character, arabic

I have problem with ( `م` ) arabic character in .htaccess RewriteRule .

The problem is :

when I open url `localhost/site/cat/مرئيات` I get error page like this :

[image: screenshoot1]

But when I change it to `localhost/site/cat/برئيات` by changing the ( `م` ) character or delete it, It work fine like this :

[image: screenshoot2]

Other arabic character is work fine so where is the wrong in my case?

My .htaccess file content:

```
Options None
Options FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' .html
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/?$ cat.php?title=$1 [NC,L]
```

Please help and thanks.

Comment: try RewriteRule ^(.)$ cat.php?title=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work on my localhost by changing the rewriterule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/.]+)$ cat.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So it matches any character other than "/" or ".". I'm not quite sure why it didn't accept your version though.
Make sure to delete your cache before refreshing!